# Ubuntu - get software information using dpkg -

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dpkg

I want to get information about installed software in Ubuntu.
I listed the installed software using `dpkg --list` but when i want to display more info using `dpkg -p firefox` i get :

```
dpkg-query: package 'firefox' is not available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
```

and the package is installed :

```
dpkg --list | grep firefox

ii  firefox                                       43.0.4+build3-0ubuntu0.15.10.1             amd64        Safe and easy web browser from Mozilla
ii  firefox-locale-en                             43.0.4+build3-0ubuntu0.15.10.1             amd64        English language pack for Firefox
ii  unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks                  0.1+13.10.20130809.1-0ubuntu1              all          Firefox bookmarks scope for Unity
```

In CentOS i used `rpm -qa` to list installed software and `rpm -qi {package_name}` to get info with no issue. But rpm don't work in Ubuntu so i need to use dpkg. How can i get software info in Ubuntu ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about solving a programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could `dpkg-query -s firefox` answer your question? :)